# Not able to set up OmniSharp for emacs

Tags: emacs, omnisharp

I recently started to work with emacs and get stuck trying to set up OmniSharp (in order to code Unity scripts)
I installed the package, put the folder with OmniSharp.exe in a correct place. And it give me this error "Could not find Omnisharp executable. Please set the omnisharp-server-executable-path to a valid path" 
Could you help me with that?

```
(setq auto-save-default null))
(setq omnisharp-server-executable-path "D:\\Program Files\\Emacs\\deps\\OmniSharp.exe")
(add-hook 'csharp-mode-hook 'omnisharp-mode)
```

Link to full .emacs file
https://yadi.sk/d/YWurk9bm3K497a

Comment: Please paste your .emacs file as a part of your question, instead of a link to screenshot. It's short and it's a text file.

Comment: Done. Thanks for asking me to do that)

Comment: You're still linking to an external resource. Please paste the relevant part of your config _inline_. If you select it and hit Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button it will be formatted as code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've done it too :)

Comment: Try this: `(setq omnisharp-server-executable-path "D:/Program Files/Emacs/deps/OmniSharp.exe")`

Comment: Hm..Looks like it doesn't change anything